# Как запретить отправку писем в MS Outlook, содержащих ключевые слова

Tags: python, outlook

Необходимо перед отправкой писем проверить письмо в формате ".docx", ".pdf", ".xlsx", ".jpg", содержащих три неизменных ключевых слова, расположенных в правом верхнем углу листа. Можно хотя бы для ".docx". Можете дать наводку или подсказку с применением надстроек или python... Работать всё должно в фоновом режиме. Пользователем MS Outlook будет обычный юзер без навыков программирования.

Comment: Здесь может подойти [VBA для Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/using-visual-basic-for-applications-in-outlook)